# Sharing list data between sites

Tags: data-view-web-part, bcs

I have a list on a sub-site that I want to share via Drop Down List with a Calendar on the root site.  ie. When you add or modify a Calendar entry, one of the columns will be a Drop Down List populated by the Title column of the List on the sub-site.

What is the best way to do this?  A `DataView Web Part` might be able to, but that looks really complicated and seems to require Visual Studio when I'd rather just use SharePoint Designer if possible.  The other option is using `BCS`, but due to the way the SharePoint Databases work, there isn't a single table where I can pull the values I need.  I could probably do it via a View, but I still don't know where these list items are stored which makes this a difficult option too.  Is there a 3rd option I have missed or are one of the other 2 my best bet?  This is on 2010 Foundation if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a hurry, so I don't have time to verify this, but this potentially helps to solve the issue for you: http://sympmarc.com/2010/11/02/using-a-datasource-in-a-data-view-web-part-dvwp-in-a-different-site-in-sharepoint-designer-2010/